# What is the correct way todo firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, jwt

My goal is to only use the firebase authentication, but when I authenticate with firebase I receive a JWT 900~1000 characters long. I would not like to have this amount of characters on every request to my API server. Is there any other way to get a smaller JWT?

Comment: I hope no. JWT is thing which will help you from intruders. Whenever you request to API server with jwt so you can validate the incoming the http request

Comment: Firebase has documentation on how to [Create Custom Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

Comment: You're right MuruGan, but i would like to know if there is a way to make a shorter JWT. I'll check your suggestion Joseph Webber.